# How to display data by rolling day for three months when data has datestamp for state change by column

Tags: sql-server, date

I have data formatted like this:

| ID | Date Created | Date Ready to Start | Date In Progress | Date Dev Complete | Date Test Complete | Date Accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 12:01:15 | 2021-11-02 14:01:15 | 2021-11-04 05:01:15 | 2021-11-04 12:01:15 | 2021-11-05 12:01:15 | 2021-11-06 12:01:15 |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 12:01:45 | NULL | 2021-11-03 12:01:15 | NULL | NULL | 2021-11-05 12:01:15 |
| 3 | 2021-11-03 11:11:05 | 2021-11-04 12:01:15 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 2021-11-05 19:31:45 | 2021-11-05 12:01:15 | 2021-11-06 12:01:15 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | 2021-11-04 13:21:25 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

and I need it formatted like this:

| Date | Created | Ready to Start | In Progress | Dev Complete | Test Complete | Accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-01 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-11-02 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-11-03 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-11-04 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-11-05 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-11-06 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

with rolling dates going back 3 months from current date.

I am unsure of how to start this... Would I union a recursive table creating the rolling calendar to the existing data or would I do a series of custom selects for counts and then group by date?

Comment: Create your 3-month period and then outer-join to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Today date = GetDate();
DECLARE @MinDate date = DateAdd(month, -3, @Today);
DECLARE @DayCount int = 1 + DateDiff(day, @MinDate, @Today);

WITH cteNumbers As
(
    /* Use a tally-table here if you have one: */
    SELECT TOP (@DayCount)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) As N
    FROM
        sys.all_columns
),
cteCalendar As
(
    SELECT
        DateAdd(day, N, @MinDate) As [Date],
        DateAdd(day, N + 1, @MinDate) As NextDay
    FROM
        cteNumbers
)
SELECT
    C.[Date],
    (
        SELECT Count(1) 
        FROM YourTable As T 
        WHERE T.[Date Created] >= C.[Date]
        And T.[Date Created] < C.NextDay
    ) As [Created],
    (
        SELECT Count(1) 
        FROM YourTable As T 
        WHERE T.[Date Ready to Start] >= C.[Date]
        And T.[Date Ready to Start] < C.NextDay
    ) As [Ready to Start],
    ...
FROM
    cteCalendar As C
;
```